# Density of a Normal RV whose mean is drawn from a Normal Distribution (Compound Distribution)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to compute the density of a random variable that is normal distributed, where the mean of the distribution is itself drawn from a normal distribution.

I would like to find the best estimate of $\mu$ given $c$, where $\mu, c$ are defined:

\begin{align*} c \sim N(\lambda, 1)\\
 \lambda \sim N(\mu,1) \end{align*}

Given that we have no prior on $\mu$ I assume the maximum likelihood is the best approach to this question.

Wikipedia says 
"Compounding a Gaussian distribution with mean distributed according to another Gaussian distribution yields a Gaussian distribution." but offers no reference for this. I cannot work this out myself and have no clue where to look for lecture notes or textbooks on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will find that if $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $Y \sim N(X,\tau^2)$ then $Y \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2+\tau^2)$. Consider $Z=Y-X \sim N(0,\tau^2)$ independent of $X$, and then consider $Y=X+Z$.

So in your question $c \sim N(\mu,2)$, and given $c$ the obvious estimator for $\mu$ is $c$.

Comment: Thank you! What would you suggest as the best way to verify this for myself (so that I learn how to deal with this kind of problem in the future)? I tried using the convolution kind of approach but failed to make the terms work out for me..

Comment: My "Consider..." provides a theoretical justification.  You could check empirically, for example in R with something like `n <- 100000; mu <- 2015; x <- rnorm(n,mean=mu,sd=1); c <- rnorm(n,mean=x, sd=1); mean(c); sd(c)^2; qqnorm(c)`

Comment: Thank you again!

I see that the "consider" part is a theoretical argument / proof - I had meant "are you aware of other analytical / theoretical approaches to this question that do not rely on this 'neat' trick/fact about the Normal distribution as heavily?" 

Simply because I sometimes have trouble applying these kind of immediate methods if I haven't worked through the "long version" myself. 

But that R code is certainly a good way to "check" the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more elegant ways, but if you want to explicitly calculate the full distribution here you can do so by considering the distribution of $c$ as a compound distribution and carrying out the integration

$p(c)=\int p(c|\lambda)p(\lambda)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda$

with

$p(c|\lambda)\propto\mathrm{e}^{-(c-\lambda)^2/2}$

$p(\lambda) \propto\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda^2/2}$

which results in another Gaussian distribution

$p(c) \propto\mathrm{e}^{-(\lambda/\sqrt{2})^2/2}$

i.e., a Gaussian with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma^2=2$.