# Normal distribution with mean coming from normal distribution

Tags: calculus, normal-distribution

this is my first time writing here. I have been looking the whole day in this page and others and I couldn't find the answer, even if it seems trivial to me.

Given a normal distribution $N(m,s_1^2)$, what is the distribution of $N(N(m,s_1),s_2^2)$?

I know by simulation that it will follow $N(m,s_1^2+s_2^2)$. This property has a name? Where can I find a demonstration for this?

Thank you in advance.

By the way, I found this other post in which is explained:
[Density of a Normal RV whose mean is drawn from a Normal Distribution (Compound Distribution)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484451/density-of-a-normal-rv-whose-mean-is-drawn-from-a-normal-distribution-compound)

The explanation is the following:
You will find that if $X∼N(μ,σ^2)$ and $Y∼N(X,τ^2)$ then $Y∼N(μ,σ^2+τ^2)$. Consider $Z=Y−X∼N(0,τ^2)$ independent of X, and then consider Y=X+Z.
However I find unclear the step $Z=Y−X∼N(0,τ^2)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I didn't know about MathJax, I will use it in the future, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X = x$, fixed. Then $Y \sim N(x,\tau^2)$, so $Y - x \sim N(0,\tau^2)$. Basically what is said is that $Z\mid X = x \sim N(0,\tau^2)$ for every possible value of $x$, hence $Z \sim N(0,\tau^2)$, i.e. conditioning doesn't change the distribution.